# Calculating the cochain complex of $S^2 \times S^4. $

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, cw-complexes, k-theory

Calculating the cochain complex of $S^2 \times S^4. $

**My calculation:**

$C^6 = \mathbb{Z}$

$C^5 = 0$

$C^4 = \mathbb{Z}$

$C^3 = 0 $

$C^2 = \mathbb{Z}$

$C^1 = 0$

$C^0 = \mathbb{Z}$

Am I correct?

Also, my procedure in the calculation was just using the homology groups of the sphere, is that correct?
My professor told us the procedure in a fast way that I did realize it, could anyone tell me the general procedure of calculating the cochain complex?

Comment: What chain complex associated to this space? If you are talking about the cellular chain complex you need to give a CW decomposition of the space (perhaps you will answer your question if you think about what CW decomposition products have).

Comment: the CW- structure of the space is 1-0 cell, 1-2cell, 1-4 cell and 1 - 6cell @ConnorMalin am I correct?

Comment: This is one CW structure you can give it that comes from the product CW structure of the 2-cell structures on each of your spheres. This is the easiest structure to use to compute (co)homology because all the differentials have to be 0.

Comment: @ConnorMalin so what about the answers to my questions above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C,C',D$ and $D'$ are chain complexes with $H_*(C) = H_*(C')$ and $H_*(D) = H_*(D')$ then $H_*(C \otimes D) = H_*(C' \otimes D')$.

(To prove this use the formula for the homology of tensor product of two chain complexes found on the last page [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~taylor/Math60440/Handouts/18/Handout18.pdf))

In particular if we have $X,Y$ be two $CW-$complexes with $C = C_*(X)$, $C'_n = H_n(X_n,X_{n-1})$, $D = C_*(Y)$ and $D'_n = H_n(Y_n, Y_{n-1})$

Then we have $H_*(C)=H_*(X) = H_*^{CW}(X) = H_*(C')$ and by the same token $H_*(D) = H_*(D')$ so we also know that $H_*(X \times Y) = H_*(C \otimes D) = H_*(C' \otimes D')$,

Basically what I'm saying is that the homology of the tensor product of the two $CW-$homology chain complexes actually gives you the singular homology of the product of the two spaces. I.e what you're doing is valid.

Comment: Could you please look at this if you have time https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618306/verify-that-langle-alpha-cup-beta-u-rangle-langle-beta-alpha-cap-u-ra ?

Comment: @Secretly At this point I'm practically reading Jeffrey Stroms book for you, can you not solve any of these problems for yourself? I really don't want to come off as rude, try and solve some of these yourself, I can help you with them in a couple of days if you are still struggling. It seems like you are not understanding some fundamental concepts that are covered in the book if you have this many questions. Try and look at the definitions of the things involved in the exercise!

Comment: Ok thank you. you helped me a lot I appreciate this :). I will help myself and if I have any questions I will ask you. Could you just suggest what to read exactly to solve that question?

Comment: I don't know exactly how Strom defines the cup and cap product, I think he does it from a homotopy viewpoint and not from an algebraic viewpoint like I did in one of my answers (not sure) so I don't think I could even help you with that. Just read the definitions/theorems you might think are relevant and be persistent with the problem. It's always worth it in the end to work through a problem on your own, you will understand it much better that way! Always happy to help